# Programmatically check iMessage support of contact

Tags: ios, objective-c, imessage

I am developing an app that loads the contacts in a `UITableView` on my iPhone. It works fine, my issue is I want to know whether the recipient's mobile number or email address is supporting iMessage or not using Objective-C.  Please tell me if I am not clear.

Comment: I don't think there is any public iMessage API.

Answer (score 5):

This is not available through the public SDK. If you have a jailbroken device you can use the ChatKit framework.

Comment: Thank you Mike could you send me any example code or links to do this using chat kit . I have googled for this but no examples and dont know how to start this

Comment: You might find this code useful: https://github.com/treason/WifiSMS/blob/master/wifiSMS/Classes/MyHTTPConnection.m

Answer (score 2):

There is not public API to do this in the current iOS SDK.

If you do manage to find some kind of private API to do it, your app will likely be rejected if you submit it to the App Store.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing available publicly so you should not try this if planning to upload the app on app store.